# Extract the underlying JSON objects

Tags: javascript, json

I recently got an assignment which looked somewhat like this - Extract the underlying JSON objects from the `request`.

```
A {
     B: {k:v,k:v,k:v},
     C: {k:v,k:v,k:v},
     D: {k:v,k:v,k:v},
     E: {k:v,k:v,k:v}
  }
```

i.e., they wanted me to extract `B,C,D,E` which were proper `JSON` from `A`.

When i did `console.log(typeof request);` it showed `object` but when i did `console.log(request);`, it was shown like above.

Normal `JSON` traversal using `A.B` wasn't working.

What type of `object` is it and how do i traverse it?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: What you have in this question is not JSON.  You have a *JavaScript literal object*.  JSON is a *string* containing a representation of a JS object.

Comment: Also objects cannot have multiple properties with the same name.

Comment: Also the syntax you have above is not valid. Please edit your question. And if that is literally what you were handed by an instructor, rethink your choice of educational venues.

Comment: So the question was wrong?

Comment: *"Normal JSON traversal using A.B wasn't working"* What did that attempt look like? (And yes, as everyone else has said: You're not dealing with JSON, you're just dealing with objects. If you're writing JavaScript code, and not dealing with a **string**, you're not dealing with JSON.)

Comment: @Nithin: The question above? Yes, it's unclear and incomplete. The question *you* were asked? We couldn't say.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder A.B was `undefined`

Comment: Note: Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics to make it possible for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc.,** and try to do the work. *If* you run into a *specific* problem, research it thoroughly, [search thoroughly here](/help/searching), and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. People will be glad to help.

Comment: @Nithin: Then what you're dealing with isn't as shown in the question (unless `A.A.B` works).

Comment: Just to really make sure request is what you think request is,.. try `console.log(JSON.stringify(request, null, "  "))`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's what i was thinking as `A.B` showing `undefined` but `typeof request` shown as object confused me.

Comment: Are you sure, that you call `A.B` **after** `console.log(request)`? Or are you trying to access a result before the request has returned?

Comment: @Thomas it was inside an API and the API's request was that. The format given to me was like above.

Comment: Have you tried request.A.B?

Comment: @DominikKirschenhofer Yep did it. It showed `undefined`

Comment: *"when i did console.log(request);, it was shown like above."* Can you add a screenshot of that? All due respect, I'm not sure that what you've put in the question is quite an accurate representation.

Comment: can you show the full code (relevant part) that fails, including the `console.log(typeof request);` that shows `object` and the `A.B` that shows `undefined`

Comment: Yep will update the question with the screenshots and code soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was

```
    temp = JSON.stringify(request);
    temp = temp.replace("A", "A:");
    temp = JSON.parse(temp);
```